# HOw to convert Mime format in Plain Text

Tags: winforms, pop3

I am working in a software where i have to use email confirmation. i use pop3 client for email read but some where its shows in :- "This is a message in Mime Format.  If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format."
Please help me to read this format. I am using yahoo mails only.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of RFC's on how MIME works.

MIME is actually a tree structure:

```
+-multipart/mixed
  +-multipart/related
  | +-multipart/alternative
  | |  +-text/plain
  | |  +-text/html
  | +-image/gif
  | +-image/jpeg
  +-application/x-zip-compressed
  +-application/x-zip-compressed
```

Each multipart mime object consist of one or more parts. 
Parts are separated using boundary delimiter.

**multipart/mixed** - 
is used when parts are not related (regular email with attachments)

**multipart/related** - 
is used when pars are related. 
For example HTML email that contains images used by this HTML.
(Cid protocol is used in HTML: )

**multipart/alternative** - 
specifies that parts contain same content but in different representations.
For example same text in doc format, html and plain text.

1. So first you need to parse headers,
2. Extract boundaries,
3. Build correct mime tree
4. Decode parts using correct encodings: Base64, QuotedPrintable

The main point is **this problem has been already solved**.

You can look at Lumisoft component (it has many issues but it's free).

You can also check out commercial products like mine [Mail.dll email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/).